# Как редактировать страницы tabcontrol

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

Как редактировать страницы tabcontrol в c++? 
Я добавил на Dialog новый tab, как добавить новую страницу к tabcontrol и расположить на ней(странице) элементы?
В настоящий момент я попытался расположить на существующем tabcontrol кнопку, но кнопка ложиться на Dialog, а не на tabcontrol.

Comment: tabcontrol - это "закладки" и не более. То что подразумевает переключение страниц называется "pagecontrol" и управляется немного сложнее. Если не ошибаюсь, в mfc страницы включаются через "группу" диалогов (если используются ресурсы).

Comment: Если у вас просто набор страниц, вам нужно это [msdn property sheets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774540(v=vs.85).aspx) (то что похоже на файл-свойства). Если конкретно pagecontrol то... поискать ещё mfc + pagecontrol.

Comment: @nick_n_a спасибо, посмотрю

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что для реализации pagecontrol в mfc обычно используют вызов диалоговых окон с заданием размеров и расположений предыдущих диалогов?